# Traversing back to Fragment which called the Activity in Android with some Data

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am working on an android app and using Fragments in UI layouts. In one of the fragments i needed to use a datetime picker behind a button click. I downloaded a sample datetime picker application which was implemented using dialogs in activity and i was having trouble to get it to work behind button click which was in a fragment. So what i did i just called the datetime picker activity from that button using intent which displays the datetime picker in dialog. Now after setting the date and time using picker I want that on clicking 'OK' button i traverse back to that fragment which called this activity and update the selected Date and Time from picker in a textview. How to achieve that?

Note that datetime picker activity is different from the activity in which fragments are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragments also contains life cycle same as Activity.

Just call finish() method from your Date picker activity.You will redirect to your last fragment,it will call onResume() of your fragment.And save your selected date in one static variable.

Another approach:

start your Date Picker activity

like below

```
int REC_CODE=2;
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,DataPic.class),REC_CODE);
```

In  DatePicker activity after selecting date

write below code

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("date",selecteddate);
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
```

by excecuting above code it finishes DatePick activity
then ovveride below method.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{

  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(requestCode == REQ_CODE){
               if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                   String date= data.getStringExtra("date");
}
}
```

Comment: exactly iam using finish(); currently to traverse back. But u mean to say that i need to override the onResume() method for my fragment and in that method update the textview with datetime saved statically before???

Comment: or else you can use startActivityForResult

Comment: can you elaborate on that what you mean by using startActivityForResult??